# MS Excel - Formula Only: Search within String and Return Value based on Criteria in Two Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring, return-value

With the use of an MS Excel formula only.  I have a text string in Cell E2, including a list/range of keywords in Column B (City) and Column C (State).  I would like a formula that will search within the string and return separately both the City and State in the corresponding Column Headers in Column F2 (State) and Column G2 (City) if found within the string.

The following formula below, I've used only allows me to search within the string Cell E2 and returns the matching value found within C2:C28. I would like to use a condition/criteria that if STATE is found within the string, then search Cell E2 and return matching CITY based on STATE.

=INDEX($C$2:$C$28,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$28,F2)),0))

[image]

Comment: The problem with your formula for the state is that it will get a false positive on `123 Franco st. Portland OR`  It will return 'CO' Because of `FranCO`

Comment: Hi Scott, how I've resolved the issue of getting a False Positive from occurring is that all words found within Column B (City) and Column C (State), is that I added a leading and trailing white space on each word.  Example: =CONCATENATE(" ",B2," "), as well as, a leading and trailing white space within Column E (Data).  Example: =CONCATENATE(" ",E2," ").  This method only detects and matches absolute keywords.